# HTML: how to simultaneously use sliders and add fields

Tags: html, css, slider

I'm failing at combining sliders with sums so I'd appreciate your help. I am trying to set up a screen where people rate their use of three languages from 0-100 using sliders. My goal is to simultaneously save these three ratings and also display their sum, to help orient participants. I have managed to display the ratings, but I can't figure out how to sum them. Below is my code and a picture of the output: as you can see: the sliders update but no sum is displayed >.<

[image]

```
<script> function updateTextInput1(val) {document.getElementById('textInput1').value=val;} </script>
<script> function updateTextInput2(val) {document.getElementById('textInput2').value=val;} </script>
<script> function updateTextInput3(val) {document.getElementById('textInput3').value=val;} </script>

<script>
function updateSum() {
  var textInput1 = +document.getElementById('textInput1').value;
  var textInput2 = +document.getElementById('textInput2').value;
  var textInput3 = +document.getElementById('textInput3').value;
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = textInput1 + textInput2 + textInput3;
}
</script>

    <table style="color:black;">
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>Russian:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value);">
                <input name="useRussian" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" size="3">
            </td>
            <td>%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>German:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput2(this.value);">
                <input name="useGerman" type="text" id="textInput2" value="" size="3">
            </td>
            <td>%</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>Other:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput3(this.value);">
                <input name="useOther" type="text" id="textInput3" value="" size="3">
            </td>
            <td>%</td>
        </tr>

            <tr><td>Total:</td>
        <td align="right"><input id="sum" size="3"></input>
        </td>
        <td>%</td>
    </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
```

Comment: It looks like you're not actually running the updateSum function anywhere in your project. Try adding the function to the onChange event in your inputs. Also change "innerHTML" to "value" in the function.

Comment: @Sol I added another part to my answer that might help. It is at the bottom. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your code:

- `<input id="sum" size="3"></input>` is incorrect it should be `<input id="sum" size="3" />`
- It shouldn't be `document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML` the correct way would be `document.getElementById('sum').value`
- The update function has a `+` in the `var`'s | *Ex.* `var textInput1 = +document.getElementById('textInput1').value;` it should just be `var textInput1 = document.getElementById('textInput1').value;`
- You need to clarify that you are adding numbers together, so I added `Number(textInput1)`, `Number(textInput2)`, and `Number(textInput3)`

After all those fixes I added the `updateSum();` function to each `onchange`.

**Here is a working snippet:**

```js
function updateTextInput1(val) {
  document.getElementById('textInput1').value = val;
}

function updateTextInput2(val) {
  document.getElementById('textInput2').value = val;
}

function updateTextInput3(val) {
  document.getElementById('textInput3').value = val;
}

function updateSum() {
  var textInput1 = document.getElementById('textInput1').value;
  var textInput2 = document.getElementById('textInput2').value;
  var textInput3 = document.getElementById('textInput3').value;
  document.getElementById('sum').value = Number(textInput1) + Number(textInput2) + Number(textInput3);
}
```

```html
<table style="color:black;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Russian:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value);updateSum()">
        <input name="useRussian" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>German:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput2(this.value);updateSum()">
        <input name="useGerman" type="text" id="textInput2" value="" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Other:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput3(this.value);updateSum()">
        <input name="useOther" type="text" id="textInput3" value="" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td align="right"><input id="sum" size="3" /></td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

There is a more efficient way of running Javascript too! Use this line of code:

```
function updateTextInput(id, val) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
```

**Click show snippet to see it in action.**

```js
function updateTextInput(id, val) {
  document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}

function updateSum() {
  var textInput1 = document.getElementById('textInput1').value;
  var textInput2 = document.getElementById('textInput2').value;
  var textInput3 = document.getElementById('textInput3').value;

  document.getElementById('sum').value = Number(textInput1) + Number(textInput2) + Number(textInput3);
}
```

```css
.tablestyle {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table class="tablestyle">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Russian:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput('textInput1', this.value);updateSum();">
        <input name="useRussian" type="text" id="textInput1" value="" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>German:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput('textInput2', this.value);updateSum();">
        <input name="useGerman" type="text" id="textInput2" value="" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Other:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" step="5" onchange="updateTextInput('textInput3', this.value);updateSum();">
        <input name="useOther" type="text" id="textInput3" value="" size="3">
      </td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td align="right"><input id="sum" size="3" /></td>
      <td>%</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Comment: oh wow, I know that I am not supposed to comment just to say "thanks", but that was an awesome answer. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yeah, anytime! The rules on here can be dumb at times. No worries hopefully this thread is on the down low :D

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies within

`document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = textInput1 + textInput2 + textInput3;`

You are trying to add `innerHTML` to `<input>`. Replace `innerHTML` with `value` and it should work.

Also you will need to cast `textInput` to integer with `parseInt(textInput)`

Comment: Thanks! I implemented your changes but it still doesn't work. Did it wor for you? This is the modified code:  
document.getElementById('sum').value = parseInt(textInput1) + parseInt(textInput2) + parseInt(textInput3);